# angular 2 ng-bootstrap datepicker popup always 1 month off

Tags: angular, datepicker, ng-bootstrap

For some reason ng-bootstrap datepicker returns a date 1 month off of the selected date. Ex. 2016-09-03 selected and displayed in input but the data is actually 2016-08-03.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0XPf.png)

I look at the official site demo and it behave the same way.

Does anyone have seen similar behavior with ng-bootstrap datepicker?
If so, how do you resolve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today the returned object representing dates has months that are 0-based. I assume that your expectation is to have it 1-based and I agree with you :-) This is why we are going to change in the next release, see https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/728

Comment: That's fantastic! Looking forward to the next release